# How do I start a Windows 10 app in a minimized window using cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have tried using the following code. It opens microsoft edge but does not open it minimized.

```
start /min microsoft-edge:
```

Whereas the following code does it for other applications.
eg,

```
start /min notepad.exe
```

Comment: Check to see if microsoft-edge is the main window process. It might be calling another process that shows the windows. Try calling this process directly with /min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start /min microsoft-edge:
```

This command started working on Insider preview on windows 10.

Comment: OHH! Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making a shortcut and set it to run it minimized => right click on the shortcut -> properties -> Run: Minimized.
Then run it from cmd `start shortcut.lnk`. Be sure to put it beside where you run CMD or set path.
I know this is not a direct solution but it would still work.

Comment: Thanks for the help but that wouldn't solve my purpose. I want the command so that i can use it for any app. Using your method i will have to create shortcut for each app that i want to do it. And besides that i don't think it is possible to make a shortcut for windows app,

Comment: If you mean notepad or something like that, you can. I mean for any aplication you have on pc there should be an executable somewhere. You can find it by right-clicking on search resoult in start menu and choosing "Open file location". I have some app set like this, like CPU temp meter. EDIT: I see i made a mistake, you cannot run some of them like that..

Comment: I know how to do it for notepad and other exes but I don't know how to do it with windows store apps.